# photo & caption layout issue

Tags: html, css

When [this page](http://cakefacemakeup.ie/) is displayed in a narrow browser window, a problem arises with the display of the photo captions at the bottom of the page, e.g.

[image]

As you can see, the caption extends beyond the right-hand side of the photo. Ideally I would like the photo to be the same width as the caption, but making the caption narrower to match the photo's width would also be acceptable.

The markup for a single photo and caption is

```
<div class="four columns">
  <div class="ft-work">
    <img src="images/slider/mum-daughter.jpg">
    <div class="ft-work-title text-center">
      <h5 class="alt-h">Caption??</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I discovered that if I remove this rule

```
#featured-work-slider img {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

the width of the photo matches the caption, but the image looks horribly stretched.

Comment: `width:auto` is the default value, so there are other styles at play here. It's hard to fully diagnose without knowing those.

Comment: @Faust I included a link to the page so that all the styles could be inspected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this rule in your stylesheet:

```
#featured-work-slider img {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Switching it to the following did the trick for me (for both mobile and desktop sizes).

```
#featured-work-slider img {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, remove `width: auto !important;` from the image in mobile layout. Then add this to make the aspect ratio correct: `height: 100%;`